# PHP wait for exec to finish and output the result

Tags: php, api, exec

I have a php file that takes in a couple parameters from the URL and then runs an exec command, in which i want to wait and have the results of the exec displayed. This exec command takes about 20-30 seconds to finish. It never completes because the webpage just gets an nginx 502 bad gateway error (times out).. Instead of extending nginx timeout error, as that's bad practice to have a connection hang for that long, how can i run the php's exec in the back and then have it returned on the page after it's complete?
Or is there a better way to accomplish this without using php?

Comment: you'd have to tell nginx that this particular script is long-running, so it DOESN'T time out.

Comment: Give us some more details and an example. My initial thought is you need a cron job and a cache for the webpage display

Comment: @MarcB How can I single out this script with nginx and tell it to not timeout? I tried various settings in nginx and php-fpm confs with no success.

Comment: you need to run the exec srypt asynchronously, in python for example I use celery, there is also a php client for it: https://github.com/gjedeer/celery-php

Answer (score 1):

Have the PHP trigger an exec to a script that is forked so it runs in the background (ends with `&`). The page should then return some js that periodically polls the server via ajax requests to check the original script's status. The script should output its STDOUT and STDERR to unique file(s) so that the polling script can check the status.

*Edit:* If you need to know the script's exit code wrap it in another script:

```
#/bin/bash
uniqId=$1
yourscript $uniqId &
myPid=$!
echo $myPid > $uniqId'.pid'
wait $myPid
echo $? > $uniqId'.returned'
```

Call like `./wrapper.sh someIdUniqueToClient &`. Untested, but you get the gist.

Comment: I've completed a similar task before and is the right answer.